# Add/remove drop down lists (php & jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, html

I currently have a multiple select with a list of grapes (more than 500 entries). To make it more user friendly, I would like to create the option of adding and removing drop down lists from which the user can choose the grape(s) which are in a bottle of wine.

I could find a lot of websites dealing with this, but only with text fields and most of them are written in JQuery ( for example this one: https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery ). I'm not familiar with JQuery, but it seems this is the way to go for my solution. I can use the code from this website and change it to a drop down list, but I can't figure out how to populate it.

Can someone help me out with this or point me in the right direction?

The current multiple select looks like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="15" name="SelectGrapes[]" style="width: 60em;">
    <option value = "">Unknown</option>
    <?php
    $querygrapes = 'SELECT ID, Name FROM grape WHERE name NOT IN ("DUMMY") ORDER BY Name ASC'; 
    $db = mysqli_query($link, $querygrapes);
    while ( $queryresult=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$queryresult['ID'] . '" >'.$queryresult['Name'].' '. '</option>';
    } ?>  
</select>
```

Thanks a lot,
Greggy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://select2.github.io/

Use select2. It's rich with explanations and surely will help you with your problem.

**EDIT**

Basically you just download and put the css and js then do this

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="js-example-basic-multiple" size="15" name="SelectGrapes[]" style="width: 60em;">
    <option value = "">Unknown</option>
    <?php
    $querygrapes = 'SELECT ID, Name FROM grape WHERE name NOT IN ("DUMMY") ORDER BY Name ASC'; 
    $db = mysqli_query($link, $querygrapes);
    while ( $queryresult=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$queryresult['ID'] . '" >'.$queryresult['Name'].' '. '</option>';
    } ?>  
</select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
</script>
```

**Notice the class on the select tag** Goodluck

Comment: I can't get it working :-( I only get a normal drop down. This is the head: `<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
</script>
<link href="select2/select2-4.0.3/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="select2/select2-4.0.3/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>`

Comment: Here's the body: `<body>
<?php include 'access.php'; ?>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple">
    <option value = "">Unknown</option>
    <?php
    $querygrapes = 'SELECT ID, Name FROM grape WHERE name NOT IN ("DUMMY") ORDER BY Name ASC'; 
    $db = mysqli_query($link, $querygrapes);
    while ( $queryresult=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$queryresult['ID'] . '" >'.$queryresult['Name'].' '. '</option>';
    } ?>  
</select>

</body>`

Comment: Ok, found it, the `<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
</script>` should come after the /SELECT tag in the body.

Comment: Sorry wasn't able to follow this up @Greggy , but good you got it to work :)